# Proof that no normed space is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

The notes for my functional analysis class casually state that every nontrivial normed space is not compact, but do not give a proof. I can't tell if this is because it is a trivial proof or because it is too complicated to be given inline. Is there a good proof for this? I have searched around the internet for a while and haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Consider the open cover of unit balls centered at every point in the space.

Comment: The result is false. Every zero dimensional normed space is compact.

Comment: All $1$ of them :P

Comment: If we're going to be hyperpedantic, there's only one up to canonical isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Any compact subset of any metric space is bounded.

Since any nonzero normed space is unbounded, it isn't compact.

**EDIT**

Consider any non zero Vector $x$ and any $M>0$; we have $\Vert tx\Vert=\vert t\vert\Vert x\Vert$ which Will be $>M$ for suitable $t$

Comment: It would be helpful if you demonstrated that it is indeed unbounded.

Comment: @AndresMejia: Ok ... Editing

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the trivial normed space $\{0\}$ with norm $\|0\|=0$ is compact.  So let's restrict our attention to normed spaces with dimension $\geq1$.

Let $X$ be a nontrivial normed space, and let $x\in X$ be nonzero. Now consider the sequence $\{nx:n\in\mathbb N\}$.  For each $n$ the set 
$$B_n=\{y\in X:\|nx-y\|<\frac{1}{2\|x\|}\} $$
is an open neighborhood of $nx$ which does not contain any other point in the sequence.  Thus no subsequence is convergent (why?).  Hence $X$ is not sequentially compact, and therefore $X$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X, \|•\|) $ be a normed linear space.

Claim : $X$ is compact iff $X=\{0\}$

Proof: One direction is fairly trivial.

Let us assume that $X$  is compact. Then $X$ must be bounded i.e $\exists r>0$ such that $\|x\|\le r,\forall x\in X$.

For given any $\epsilon>0$ , $\|\epsilon x\|\le r$ as $\epsilon x\in X$ .

Then $0\le \|x\|=\|\frac{\epsilon x}{\epsilon}\|\le \frac{r}{\epsilon}$

Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, $\|x\|=0$ and hence $x=0$